# php cron job every 10 minutes

Tags: php, cron

I'm trying to run a cron job so that a php script will run every 10 minutes on my server. The script updates a database. Right now my crontab looks like:

```
* /10 * * * * /usr/bin/php  /home/user/public_html/domain.com/private/update.php
```

However, the php script never seems to run. I've also tried reloading cron after updating the cron tab with :

```
  $ /etc/init.d/cron reload
```

but this didn't work either. Does my current crontab look correctly formatted? Are there specific permissions that need to be specified on a file in order for it to run a script?

Comment: This should be a superuser.com question

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There should not be a space between "*" and "/10".  It should be:

```
*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/php  /home/user/public_html/domain.com/private/update.php
```