# Run cron job to execute a php function after some fixed time

Tags: php, cron

I have read the answer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830208/php-cron-job-every-10-minutes#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830208/php-cron-job-every-10-minutes#_=_)

I have similar kind of question: I am trying to run a cron job to execute a php function which will delete some fields , after checking some conditions . So I want to know how will I run the function within that php file . Should I add the path like 'http://somename/index.php?do=dlt" or just the function something else

Comment: like the other question you call the php script via  the command line

Answer (score 2):

1: change your script to use command line parameters instead of `_GET`: the first argument is in `$argv[1]` variable

2: create cronjob like this:

`*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/script/index.php dlt`

note, that you may have to specify full path to `php` binary (`whereis php`) and to your script.

3: if there's some `include` or `require` - change path to absolute.

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke PHP CLI version like `php /path/to/file/file.php dlt` or by using wget like tool `wget http://somename/index.php?do=dlt`. In first case you must change your script to use `$argv` instead of `$_GET`. In second case it'll work right away, because it'll use http server underneath.

Comment: I have downloaded the wget-1.10.1.Now how can I use it to run the cron job? Thanks

Comment: This should work: `*/5 * * * *    /usr/bin/wget "http://somename/index.php?do=dlt"`

Comment: Sorry to ask but I am using this for first time . So can you tell me how and where I should use this?